# where i go wrong ? Json problem in MVC 3

Tags: json, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two copy of a project.

First i have and 2nd i got from other person.

when i make some changes it's work fine but

when i place all changes in another person's project :> the problem i got that json not worked in Firefox. but work in other like Chrome , firefox even IE 9.

the problem is that

"if we do something wrong why they worked in my project"

the ajax not work but in mine project they worked

```
 $(".delmem").click(function () {
                    var personID = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
                    $.post("/home/removeperson",
                        { perID: perID, gID: gID },
                    function (data) {
                    }, "json");

                document.location.reload();
                return false;
            });
```

well it's work in my project but in a another copy it's not worked when i test them it's not work only in firefox. but in my project they work.

where i go wrong tell me the thing i do wrong.

Comment: Any error message? 'It doesn't work' is not the best description of the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you get if you add the following...

```
$(".delmem").click(function () {
    alert(this.href);
    var personID = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
    ...
```

Do you get a different result in each application? The most likely issue I can think of is that you have slightly different URLs in the applications...

```
<a href="?1234">Customer</a>
```

Vs

```
<a href="http://localhost/Customer/?1234">Customer</a>
```

As an example.